# Acentuação x JSON(Jquery)

Tags: jquery, json

Como devo proceder no Jquery para que o retorno a requisição via json esteja / seja com a acentuação correta?
Atual: "Segunda, 12 de Mar&ccedil;o de 2018"
Preciso: "Segunda, 12 de Março de 2018"

Estou tentando usar isso:

```
$.ajax({
        async:false,
        type: "GET",
        url: "portal.local/servico/datas/",
        dataType: "text",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-1",
        success: function (data) {
           alert(data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: e com dataType: 'json', o que acontece?

Comment: Você está chamando esse arquivo `js` em alguma página `html`, certo? Se sim, coloque isso em sua tag `script` `<script src="example.js" charset="utf-8"> </script>`

Comment: dataType:"json" resultado é Segunda, 12 de Mar&amp;ccedil;o de 2018.

Comment: @DiegoAlbuquerque já tentou fazer o que sugeri?

Comment: Coloquei o charset="utf-8" no script e tbm não foi =/

Comment: Você tem controle do código que gera esse JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Se é uma página php que retorna json sete o seu head.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
echo json_encode(<strong>"meu array", JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```